# php code appearing in form fields - bootstrap email form

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an HTML file and a PHP file here. The form is to send an email. What is happening is that bits of "code" are appearing in the form fields. Other than that, it does work and sends an email. Once the code has been deleted from the fields and the correct info entered instead. The code is from a bootstrap email form tutorial.

[Click here for a Screenshot of what I am describing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Nw4.jpg)

Thanks guys!!

--HTML FILE--

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="Bootstrap contact form with PHP example by BootstrapBay.com.">
        <meta name="author" content="BootstrapBay.com">
        <title>Bootstrap Contact Form With PHP Example</title>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h1 class="page-header text-center">Contact Form Example</h1>
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">
                            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>">
                            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);?></textarea>
                            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMessage</p>";?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="human" class="col-sm-2 control-label">2 + 3 = ?</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="Your Answer">
                            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errHuman</p>";?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <?php echo $result; ?>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

-- PHP FILE --

```
<?php
    if ($_POST["submit"]) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $human = intval($_POST['human']);
        $from = 'Demo Contact Form'; 
        $to = 'example@domain.com'; 
        $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';

        $body ="From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name']) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }

        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }

        //Check if message has been entered
        if (!$_POST['message']) {
            $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
        }
        //Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
        if ($human !== 5) {
            $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
        }
// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
    }
}
    }
?>
```

Comment: Simple, name your extension `.php` or instruct Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP.

Comment: You're writing the php code into a plain html file? To do that you'll need to use .htaccess to create an *AddType* modification or use a friendly url which 'translates' php to html.

Comment: *"Thanks guys!!"* - [You're welcome...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461838/php-code-appearing-in-form-fields-bootstrap-email-form#comment45249522_28461838) ;-)

Comment: So you're saying to rename index.html to index.php ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- 
I changed it to index.php and it did stop the code appearing in the fields but the warnings aren't appearing. 'Please enter a valid email address' for example. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes, I know why. See my answer that I've posted below.

Comment: Great stuff, thanks! Putting everything in the one file and making that edit fixed it. 
Only annoying thing is previewing my whole site in dreamweaver now. I can live with that though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is with your script, is that if you have it in two seperate files, it won't work.

*(Not so fast Fred)...* It will still work, but it won't work as intended in order to show you the error message(s) if one or more fields have not been filled, being the whole purpose with your code.

It needs to be inside a single file (PHP first, then your HTML form) *sidenote: the order isn't important; the choice is yours*. Plus, you will also need to modify your code so that it contains a valid `From:`. *More on this below.*

This, on top of what I already said about it must be a `.php` extension.

Therefore you will need to change this line:

```
$from = 'Demo Contact Form';
```

to:

```
$from = "From: ". $name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n";
```

in order to show the person's name in the Email's from, but at the same time having an Email address as the "From:"

Otherwise, it will look as if it were coming from your own server, rather than the person's Email.

*(I've tested for myself)*

For more information on the `mail()` function, visit PHP.net:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php